# Probability of Ending up Sick after 3 rounds

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Start with two people "sick" in a group with a total of 100. In round 1, each person shares with another person. The two sick people can share with anyone. If they share with each other then the number of sick people remains at 2. They continue this for 2 more rounds. If person A had already shared with person B then they can't share again in future rounds. If person A shared with B and person C with D, then person B can share with person D. If two sick people share with each other than they both remain sick. At the end of round three what is the probability that 6 people are sick? 8 People? 10? and so forth until 16.

Comment: Already asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3362855/probability-of-getting-sick

Comment: How do you pick who they share with?  Presumably you can pick a random other person for 1, but if you pick 2 does 2 have to share with 1?  For 3 rounds, just compute the chance of each number of sick people after each round.

Comment: Your previous version was put on hold for being unclear.  You have not done anything to clarify.  My comment was written independently of the previous question.  You have to specify carefully how the people to share with are chosen for the question to be able to be answered.  For a start, after one round, you have $2$ or $4$ people sick.  What is the chance it is $2$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Probability of Getting Sick](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3362855/probability-of-getting-sick)

Comment: People randomly chose who to share with but if 1 shares with 2 then 2 shares with 1